# Davinci Resolve: The rendered output has video that lags 1-2 seconds behind audio

Tags: davinci-resolve

I record an MP4 video with IPEVO document camera. There is no out of sync problem. Here is the metadata of the MP4 video (as the media source).

```
General
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (mp41/isom)
File size                                : 499 MiB
Duration                                 : 8 min 50 s
Overall bit rate                         : 7 897 kb/s


Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.1
Format settings                          : 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=15
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 8 min 50 s
Bit rate                                 : 7 717 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 024 pixels
Height                                   : 768 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Standard                                 : Component
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.327
Stream size                              : 488 MiB (98%)


Audio
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 8 min 50 s
Source duration                          : 8 min 49 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 175 kb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 192 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 11.1 MiB (2%)
Source stream size                       : 11.1 MiB (2%)
mdhd_Duration                            : 530057
```

However, if I edit it with Davinci Resolve 17 Beta, the rendered output has out-of-sync issue. The video lags about 1-2 seconds behind the audio.

Could you tell me what causes this issue?

## Edit 1

Is it due to the difference of frame rate? The following is taken from the above metadata.

```
Video Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Audio Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
```

## Edit 2

I dragged and drop the MP4 clip onto the timeline. The end part of the timeline is shown as follows.

[image]

There are some delayed frames at the end. How to fix this?

Comment: FPS means something different for audio. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235189/video-is-25fps-audio-50-fps

Comment: @Matt: Thank you for informing it. It is very helpful.